# Backbone - copy paste url

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, iis-7, single-page-application

I've created a small website by using backbone.js. It's hosted in IIS 7.

The routing:

```
 routes: {
            "/": "index",
            "": "index",
            "detailedpage/:id": "detailedpage",
            '*notFound': 'index'
        }
```

I've a problem when I try to copy/paste an url.
If I want to access directly to

> http://www.anydomain.com/detailedpage/1234

it's not working. I can see in the developper tools an internal server error for 1234, path "/detailedpage".

The strange thing is if I access first to

> http://www.anydomain.com/

and after copy/paste the url

> http://www.anydomain.com/detailedpage/1234

it's working.

Can you please tell me if I need to enable/disable any handler in IIS?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include a hashtag is not a solution. It's just tell to the browser what is the root url.
The root cause is probably the redirection to the index page which is not correctly working.

The solution I did is to put the html into a view in a MVC application. All requests are redirect to the same controller, which return this new view. So I'm sure that all request are redirect to the index page.

Answer (score 2):

Since backbone is doing the routing, your browser has to have the right content before its loaded.  If you wish to use `pushState` with `Backbone`, you have to trick your webserver into serving the same html page for all possible routes. The way we do that in `IIS` is have the `.NET` routing setup in such a way that loads the required backbone assets so it can do routing directly.

Alternatively, you can disable `pushState` in `Backbone.history.start()` and use hash based routing. (myurl/#/myroute)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't want to use the hash tag.
Do you mean that I've to redirect my error page (as the content "/detailedpage/1234" doesn't exist to the index via the configuration file?

Comment: correct. If you wish to use `pushState`, you have to have `IIS` and `.NET` serve up your backbone application in case the page 404's. That means either defining custom routes that load the same views or overwriting a 404 route to serve your app code.

Comment: It's already done. My web.config: <system.webServer> <httpErrors> <error statusCode="403" subStatusCode="14" path="/" responseMode="ExecuteURL" /> <error statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" path="/" responseMode="ExecuteURL" /> <error statusCode="404" subStatusCode="2" path="/" responseMode="ExecuteURL" /> <error statusCode="404" subStatusCode="3" path="/" responseMode="ExecuteURL" /> </httpErrors> </system.webServer>
But doesn't work...

Comment: when you navigate directly to that url, does it load your app?

Comment: I can only see the header. Nothing which is dynamically generated, like information to display on the page based on the id in the url. In the developper tools, I see that all JavaScript files are not downloaded (and so the one which contain the routes is not downloaded).

Comment: that means your ISS/.NET isn't actually serving them up.  I'd guess the solution you used to redirect the 404's isn't working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

These are client routes, so you begin with a #.

http://www.anydomain.com/#detailedpage/1234